# Hostname configuration: name resolution vs. meeting SW requirements

Tags: hostname, rhel-6

For a software installation, I have the following requirements:

```
hostname --fqdn
    This command must return the FQDN of the server (for example, server2.subdomain.example.com).
hostname und hostname -s
    This command must return the first part of the FQDN, that is the host name (for example, server2).
```

In the original configuration, `hostname` returned the FQDN as well.

To solve this, I changed `/etc/sysconfig/network` to contain the following:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=server2
GATEWAY=1.2.3.4
```

and in `/etc/hosts`, I added the line

```
127.0.0.1   server2.subdomain.example.com server2
```

HOSTNAME was previously the FQDN. The requirements as stated above are met now. However, running `ping server2` from another server within the same network (say server3) does not resolve anymore, which it did previously. Now I need to enter the FQDN here.

Is there any way to achieve both?

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way (presuming you don't have too many servers) is to edit `/etc/hosts` on all servers involved, so that every server knows the FQDN of every other server.

If you need anything beyond that, or if there are enough servers involved for the above to be impractical, you might want to set up a local DNS server that acts as a master for your zone, and forwards any requests for anything else to the DNS server they're using to day.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to rewrite all the /etc/hosts files, I found the following solution:

edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`
add this line at the end:

```
SEARCH "subdomain.example.com"
```

If you add the "search" parameter directly to `/etc/resolv.conf`, it will be overwritten by an active NetworkMananger at the next restart.